# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple I get an TypeError:

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array,identity,diagonal
from math import sqrt,asin,acos,sin,cos,atan

def householder(A):

    n = len(A)
    print(n)
    v = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.double)
    print(v)
    u = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.double)
    print(u)
    z = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.double)
    print(z)

    for k in range(0, n - 2):

        if np.isclose(A[k + 1][k], 0.0):
            α = -np.sqrt(np.sum(A[(k + 1) :, k] ** 2))
        else:
            α = -np.sign(A[k + 1][k]) * np.sqrt(np.sum(A[(k + 1) :, k] ** 2))

        two_r_squared = α ** 2 - α * A[k + 1][k]
        v[k] = 0.0
        v[k + 1] = A[k + 1][k] - α
        v[(k + 2) :] = A[(k + 2) :, k]
        u[k:] = 1.0 / two_r_squared * np.dot(A[k:, (k + 1) :], v[(k + 1) :])
        z[k:] = u[k:] - np.dot(u, v) / (2.0 * two_r_squared) * v[k:]

    for l in range(k + 1, n - 1):

        A[(l + 1) :, l] = (
            A[(l + 1) :, l] - v[l] * z[(l + 1) :] - v[(l + 1) :] * z[l]
        )
        A[l, (l + 1) :] = A[(l + 1) :, l]
        A[l, l] = A[l, l] - 2 * v[l] * z[l]

    A[-1, -1] = A[-1, -1] - 2 * v[-1] * z[-1]
    A[k, (k + 2) :] = 0.0
    A[(k + 2) :, k] = 0.0

    A[k + 1][k] = A[k + 1][k] - v[k + 1] * z[k]
    A[k][k + 1] = A[k + 1][k]

    print(A)

A= [ [3,2,1,2] , [2,-1,1,2] , [1,1,4,30] , [2,2,3,1] ]

new= householder(A)

print (new)
```

I get an TypeError:

α = -np.sign(A[k + 1][k]) * np.sqrt(np.sum(A[(k + 1) :, k] ** 2)) TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I have try to brake the code up like [a],[b],[c] but error persist.

Comment: You are using `A` as if it was a numpy array, but it is a list.

Comment: You can Use np.array() in the list you are passing

```
A = np.array(A)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve this with following code:

```
A= np.array( [ [3,2,1,2] , [2,-1,1,2] , [1,1,4,30] , [2,2,3,1] ])
```